# click to add border to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page with multiple div. When the user clicks on the body, all div elements will have their border changed to red. However, when the user clicks on a div, only that div will have their border changed to blue.Every other div element will remain with a red border. this is my code so far:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if (!target.closest($('div')).length) {
        //I want the border of all div on the page to change to red
        $('div'). css('border', '2px solid red');
    } else if (target.closest($('div')).length) {
        //Here just the div that was clicked on will have its border changed to blue
        $(this).css('border', '2px solid blue');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/74pzJ/4/

```
$('body').on("click", function(e) {
    $("div").css('border', '2px solid red');
    $(e.target).closest("div").css('border', '2px solid blue');
});
```

**Documentation**

- `on` - http://api.jquery.com/on/
- `not` - http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- `css` - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: This, +1. Make sure to use `on` instead of `click`

Comment: What if there is actually an element inside the div? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/74pzJ/3/

Comment: @aquinas The OP didn't provide any markup, so it's just an example. Beside that it's impossible to foresee all the potential hiccups related to *"what if"*. If the OP wants a solution for his exact case, than he/she has to provide the exact markup

Comment: @ZoltanToth, the OP *did* however provide code that was checking to see if the target of the event was inside of a div. `else if (target.closest($('div')).length)`.

Comment: @ZoltanToth. Nice, very clean.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use event.stopPropagation() method here of jquery..in your function

because your click event is bubbling up to other divs

Comment: -1 -- the event in the OP's code is bound to the body element, the click event occurs on the div then bubbles up to the body, but since an event is not bound to the div, this doesn't matter. `stopPropagation` will not affect anything, since the only element with an event listener is the body itself, there isn't any more bubbling to do. Also, `stopPropagation` is not a "method of jQuery", but rather a method of the standard DOM event object itself. Minor point, that last, but important to understand what is and is not really a part of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('div').css('border', '2px solid red');    
});

$('div').click(function(e){
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid blue');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for to highlight the html tags like firebug. Maybe this is helpful for you.

```
    document.getElementById('clickable_content').addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.target.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
            e.target.className = e.target.className.replace(new RegExp(" highlight\\b", "g"), "");
        });
        e.target.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            alert(e.target.className); // clicked div or what ever
        });
        e.target.className += " highlight";
    });
```